# Ubuntu Mate question

Tags: scripts, files

I am running Ubuntu Mate 15.10-64bit on my surface pro by booting it from a USB drive. I don't want to install it on the surface pro, I just want to keep booting it from the USB drive. I always change the display properties to make everything bigger, how do I make it save these properties? It does not save them once the system is restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Your Ubuntu Mate USB must have Persistence enabled. It can only be done at the time of transferring the iso to the USB in my knowledge.

Try re-transferring the iso using Unetbootin / Linux Live USB creator and select Persistence (with 512 MB at least) in the Options.